# vertical-align: middle not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a section title which has a border on both left and right sides. Ideally, I'd like these to be vertically aligned. However, `vertical-align: middle;` isn't working and I'm not too sure why. Ideas?

CSS

```
#save-the-date {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#save-the-date #title {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#save-the-date #title h2 {
    font-size: 165%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}

#save-the-date #title .left-border {
    float: left;
    background:url('img/border.png') repeat-x -10px 0;
    width:340px;
    height:3px;
}

#save-the-date #title .right-border {
    float: right;
    background:url('img/border.png') repeat-x -10px 0;
    width:340px;
    height:3px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="save-the-date">
    <div id="title">
        <div class="left-border"></div><!-- end border -->
        <h2>Save The Date</h2>
        <div class="right-border"></div><!-- end border -->
    </div><!-- end title -->
</div><!-- end save-the-date -->
```

[image]

Comment: The floating is your problem by the way you also need to set a correct heigt for vertical-align.

Answer (score 5):

Set `display: table-cell` on the container as well as `vertical-align: middle`. This will cause CSS to treat the container as a table cell which does allow vertical alignment to be specified.

Comment: Setting `display: table-cell` caused each element to be stacked on top of one another. Any ideas why that happened/how to rectify?

Comment: `table-cell` will stack by default. You need to create a center box and apply the style to only that box. The other two `div` elements don't need to have table-cell applied to them so this doesn't pose any problem.

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding correctly, but..
I've put `h2`, which I want to be in the center, in it's own div and still didn't see changes. http://jsfiddle.net/c484z/

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/rtaaP/2/. I have simplified this even further... what I did is made everything a span and then floated the left and right border boxes. Because spans are inline elements they don't react like divs do when it comes to display properties. The `h2` is also made inline to make it react properly to the vertical centering. The CSS has been changed to better show you what exactly is going on, but you should be able to adapt this fairly easily to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I really do appreciate your thoughtful answers. I've applied the directions you gave me in the jsfiddle to my site, but things still aren't looking quite right. http://jsfiddle.net/Fkp6W/

Comment: You don't have the outer div so your CSS rules aren't applied. As a side note you should work to eliminate extraneous CSS rules because they hurt performance. For example `table tbody tr td` can generally be reduced to simply `td`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is just a single line, you can simply set the line-height to be the height of the element. [View it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvBVV/)

### HTML

```
​<p>hello</p>​
```

### CSS

```
p {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

because you use div div's display is block you can change it to `<span>`  or chanage display for example :

```
div
{display: inline-block}
```

or

> div {display: table-cell;}

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why it worked in my case... but by I could see it working by doing following:

```
div {padding-top: 0%;}
```